# Unity3d New Input System(2.8), can't reference Input Action in the editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've just updated to the new Input System from 2.7 to 2.8.

How the new Input System works is you create an input actions asset by going to Create-> Input Actions

[image: Input Actions].

This creates an asset where actions can be mapped to keys. One then create a C# script from this asset and use it in their code. Which is what I did. I called the Asset `MyInput.inputactions` and the C# script is `MyInput.cs`

[image: Asset and generated C# class]

When you use the generated C# script this way you need to reference the **asset** in your script. However, after the update, it seems this is impossible to do from the editor. When I define a **public** `MyInput` variable in my class, like so:

```
public class ShapeMover: MonoBehaviour
{
    public MyInput controls;

    private       float        _lastFallTime;
    private       float        _fallSpeed;
    private       ShapeSpawner _spawn;
    private       GameObject   _shapeToMove;
    private       Transform    _shapeToMoveTransform;
    private       bool         _isGameOver;
    private const float        _leftRotationAngle  = (float) -1.57079633;
    private const float        _rightRotationAngle = (float) 1.57079633;
}
```

It isn't exposed in the inspector:

[image]

And I get an obvious `NullReferenceException`error when I try to access the `controls` variable.

Am I doing something wrong?

How can I reference the asset from the inspector? I have tried adding     `[SerializeField]` to the public declaration, it didn't help.

I was following [this](https://youtu.be/Pzd8NhcRzVo?t=705) video and it worked fine until I updated to a newer Input System version.

For reference, this is the full ShapeMover class:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using UnityEngine.UI;

namespace _Scripts
{
    public class ShapeMover : MonoBehaviour
    {
        [SerializeField]
        public MyInput controls;

        private       float        _lastFallTime;
        private       float        _fallSpeed;
        private       ShapeSpawner _spawn;
        private       GameObject   _shapeToMove;
        private       Transform    _shapeToMoveTransform;
        private       bool         _isGameOver;
        private const float        _leftRotationAngle  = (float) -1.57079633;
        private const float        _rightRotationAngle = (float) 1.57079633;


        private void Awake()
        {
            _spawn        = FindObjectOfType<ShapeSpawner>();
            _lastFallTime = 0f;
            _fallSpeed    = GameGrid.Instance.GetFallSpeed();
            _isGameOver   = false;

            Debug.Log("Registering controls callbacks...");
            controls.Player.Movement.performed += ctx => Movement(ctx.ReadValue<Vector2>(), true);
            controls.Player.Drop.performed     += ctx => Drop();
            controls.Menu.Reset.performed      += ctx => Restart();
            controls.Menu.Pause.performed      += ctx => PauseToggle();
            SetShapeToMove();
        }

        private void Restart()
        {
            GameGrid.Instance.ResetGame();
            _isGameOver = false;
            SetShapeToMove();
        }


        private void PauseToggle()
        {
            Debug.Log("Got Pause input");
            var currentPauseState = GameGrid.Instance.IsPaused;
            //If not paused, will pause
            if (!currentPauseState)
            {
//                controls.Player.Movement.Disable();
//                controls.Player.Drop.Disable();
//                controls.Player.Menu.Disable();
//                controls.Player.Disable();
                GameGrid.Instance.IsPaused = true;
            }
            else
            {
//                controls.Player.Movement.Enable();
//                controls.Player.Drop.Enable();
//                controls.Player.Menu.Enable();
//                controls.Player.Enable();
                GameGrid.Instance.IsPaused = false;
            }
        }

        private void Drop()
        {
//            Debug.Log("Should Drop Shape!");
            bool didMove = true;
            while (didMove)
            {
                didMove = Movement(new Vector2(0, -1), false);
            }
        }

        private bool Movement(Vector2 direction, bool isFromInput)
        {
            if (isFromInput)
            {
                Debug.Log($"Got input {direction.ToString()}");
            }

            //Disable movement controls when game is over.
            if (_isGameOver)
            {
                return false;
            }

            var oldPosition = _shapeToMoveTransform.position;
            var oldRotation = _shapeToMoveTransform.rotation;
//            Transform[] children       = _shapeToMoveTransform.Cast<Transform>().ToArray();
            var didMove        = true;
            var didEndMovement = false;

            GameGrid.Instance.RemoveShapeFromGrid(_shapeToMoveTransform);

            if (direction.x < 0)
            {
                didMove = MoveLeft();
            }
            else if (direction.x > 0)
            {
                didMove = MoveRight();
            }
            else if (direction.y > 0)
            {
                didMove = RotateLeft();
            }
            else if (direction.y < 0)
            {
                didMove = MoveDown();

                if (!didMove)
                {
                    didEndMovement = true;
                }
            }

            //If Shape didn't move, restore previous position.
            if (!didMove)
            {
                _shapeToMoveTransform.position = oldPosition;
                _shapeToMoveTransform.rotation = oldRotation;
            }

            GameGrid.Instance.AddShapeToGrid(_shapeToMoveTransform);

//            Debug.Log($"Shape {_shapeToMove.name} Position after movement Did Move: {didMove.ToString()}");

//            Transform[] children = _shapeToMoveTransform.Cast<Transform>().ToArray();

//            var lowestChild = children.OrderBy(x => x.position.y).First();

//            Debug.Log($"{lowestChild.position.ToString()}");

            if (didEndMovement)
            {
                GameGrid.Instance.ClearRows(_shapeToMoveTransform);
                _isGameOver = GameGrid.Instance.IsGameOver(_shapeToMoveTransform);
                if (!_isGameOver)
                {
                    SetShapeToMove();
                }
            }

            return didMove;
        }

        private void SetShapeToMove()
        {
            _shapeToMove          = _spawn.SpawnShape();
            _shapeToMoveTransform = _shapeToMove.transform;
        }

        private void Update()
        {
            if (_isGameOver)
            {
                return;
            }

            if (GameGrid.Instance.IsPaused)
            {
                return;
            }


            var time = Time.time;
            if (!(time - (_lastFallTime + _fallSpeed) > 0))
            {
                return;
            }

            Movement(new Vector2(0, -1), false);
            _lastFallTime = time;
            _fallSpeed    = GameGrid.Instance.GetFallSpeed();
        }


        private bool MoveLeft()
        {
            _shapeToMoveTransform.position += Vector3.right;
            return GameGrid.Instance.CanMove(_shapeToMoveTransform);
        }

        private bool MoveRight()
        {
            _shapeToMoveTransform.position += Vector3.left;
            return GameGrid.Instance.CanMove(_shapeToMoveTransform);
        }

        private bool MoveDown()
        {
            _shapeToMoveTransform.position += Vector3.down;
            return GameGrid.Instance.CanMove(_shapeToMoveTransform);
        }


        private bool RotateLeft()
        {
            _shapeToMoveTransform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
//            foreach (Transform child in _shapeToMoveTransform)
//            {
//                RotateTransform(child, _leftRotationAngle);
//            }

            return GameGrid.Instance.CanMove(_shapeToMoveTransform);
        }

        private void RotateTransform(Transform transformToRotate, float rotationAngleRadian)
        {
            var currentLocalPosition = transformToRotate.localPosition;
            var currentX             = currentLocalPosition.x;
            var currentY             = currentLocalPosition.y;

            var rotatedX = currentX * Mathf.Cos(rotationAngleRadian) - currentY * Mathf.Sin(rotationAngleRadian);
            var rotatedY = currentX * Mathf.Sin(rotationAngleRadian) + currentY * Mathf.Cos(rotationAngleRadian);

            transformToRotate.localPosition = new Vector2(rotatedX, rotatedY);
//            Debug.Log($"Position after rotation is: {transformToRotate.localPosition.ToString()}");
        }

        private bool RotateRight()
        {
            _shapeToMoveTransform.Rotate(0, 0, -90);
            return GameGrid.Instance.CanMove(_shapeToMoveTransform);
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            Debug.Log("Controls Enabled...");
            controls.Enable();
        }

//        private void OnDisable()
//        {
//            Debug.Log("Controls Disabled...");
//            controls.Disable();
//        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just as you said, you can't reference the new generated input class anymore.
To make it works, i instantiated the class, and use the SetCallbacks method, like this :

```
private MyInput _inputs;

public void Awake()
{
    _inputs = new MyInput();
}
```

Truth be told, i don't know if it's the intended way of using the input class, but it works.

**EDIT :**

Starting from the 2.8 preview, an interface is automatically generated. I can only recommend it, cause it's very easy to use, you just need to inherits from IYourActionsSetNameActions and add the callbacks. (Also, you have to enable / disable the actions set, but you should be able to do it in another script)

Here is a complete base example, using your naming :

```
public class ShapeMover : MonoBehaviour, MyInput.IPlayerActions
{
    private MyInput _inputs;

    public void Awake()
    {
        _inputs = new MyInput();
        _inputs.Player.SetCallbacks(this);
    }

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        _inputs.Player.Enable();
    }

    public void OnDisable()
    {
        _inputs.Player.Disable();
    }

    public void OnMovement(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        Vector2 delta = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
        transform.position += new Vector3(delta.x, 0, delta.y);
    }

    public void OnDrop(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        //TODO
    }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I instantiated the `_inputs` variable as you said and it seems to work fine. I didn't do `_inputs.Player.SetCallbacks(this);` I'm unsure what it does...

Comment: Very true. I didn't see you were not using the new generated interface (which is now automatically generated starting 2.8). I made an edit to show how you can use it, as i find it more easy to use :)

Comment: thank you! Where did you find the documentation for this?

Comment: Well, sadly i don't think there is any up-to-date yet. I can only give you the link to the github : https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/InputSystem. The docs are not really up-to-date, but it's the most complete. Sometimes i also browse the forum, it can also be helpful (https://forum.unity.com/forums/new-input-system.103/)

Comment: This is the only implementation that worked for me!